# Mysql query returns 0 rows when not using a table mentioned in "FROM"

Tags: mysql

This query returns 0 elements:

```
SELECT `table1`.`id` FROM `table1`,`table2` WHERE `table1`.`id`='222' ;
```

However I expect to have a result because this query returns one element:

```
SELECT `table1`.`id` FROM `table1` WHERE `table1`.`id`='222' ;
```

Is there a MySQL parameter to set in order to get a result with the first query where `table2` is not used?

Comment: What is your first query suposed to do? you are selecting from two tables but you are not joining them

Comment: Using `table1`,`table2` will cause "Cartesian product" that for most of the solution will be the Ineffective way of solving a problem. What is your goal for the first query ?

Comment: I simplified the problem, in fact, my real query is more complicated.

Comment: Is there a solution to unset the "Cartesian product" effect ?

Comment: Thanks to you I found the solution: table2 was empty, if I insert a row in it, the queries give the same result.

Comment: Cartesian product effect .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first query you used 2 table but in the second query you used one table.Because of this the result is different.

If you not specify join explicitly also it will use `Cartesian product`

Comment: yes I know, but the 2 queries are delivering the same result on a former database instance. I installed yesterday a new instance, and they does not..

Comment: in previous database you might have the data that is supporting to get that out out